# XSLT Reading from File

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a code that reads my Xslt templates from Resources but I have to make it reads from seperated files in root directory of application. So this is my code:

```
            docs[0] = new DocumentReferenceType
            {
                ID = new IDType { Value = new Guid().ToString() },
                IssueDate = new IssueDateType { Value = DateTime.Now },
                DocumentType = new DocumentTypeType { Value = "xslt" },
                Attachment = new AttachmentType
                {
                    EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject = new EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObjectType
                    {
                        filename = "customxslt.xslt",
                        encodingCode = "Base64",
                        mimeCode = "applicationxml",
                        format = "",
                        characterSetCode = "UTF-8",
                        Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Properties.Resource1.XSLTFile)

                    }
                }
            };
            return docs;
```

What should I write to "Properties.Resource1.XSLTFile" read from XSLTFile.xslt in root directory? I tried to write this:

```
        string _filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            _filePath += @"\XSLTFile.xslt";
```

And I changed "Properties.Resource1.XSLTFile" with "_filePath " there but it gave me this error: "HTML conversion failed: XSLT compilation error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got help and i am sharing maybe there will be someone who needs it

```
            string _filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            _filePath += @"\xslt\earsiv.xslt";
            string xs = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_filePath);

            docs[0] = new DocumentReferenceType
            {
                ID = new IDType { Value = new Guid().ToString() },
                IssueDate = new IssueDateType { Value = DateTime.Now },
                DocumentType = new DocumentTypeType { Value = "xslt" },
                Attachment = new AttachmentType
                {
                    EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject = new EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObjectType
                    {
                        filename = "customxslt.xslt",
                        encodingCode = "Base64",
                        mimeCode = "applicationxml",
                        format = "",
                        characterSetCode = "UTF-8",
                        Value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xs)
                    }
                }
            };
            return docs;
```